# Excel formatting macro taking too long

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I have a macro that fires off every time a checkbox is clicked on or off.  The macro does all kinds of things including creating a new sheet and copying over columns from the sheet that contains the checkbox's.

In finishing up this project I added to the macro so the new sheet would be properly formatted for printing.  Adding this has slowed the macro down to being unusable.  The user will be selecting several checkboxes and every time they do it takes several seconds for the formatting portion of the macro to run.  It's not going to work for the user to click and wait, click and wait, ........

This macro does so much that it seems impossible that the formatting would take up to 3 or 4 times longer than everything else combined.  I have tried taking out all the unnecessary line items, but it's still running way to slow.

I've added just the formatting code to this post as everything else is working perfectly.

```
Sub Format()

    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        '.PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = "$A:$A"
    End With

    Application.PrintCommunication = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you copying the checkboxes or any other form, activex, or shape items, formulas or such?  Or are you just copying the values of the three columns?

Comment: How much data is present in the worksheet you are formatting? This take .16 seconds to run on a completely blank sheet, so a lot of data could slow this down.

Comment: I added the "Sheets.Add" command to your format code to force a new sheet to be the active sheet the active sheet and your formatting code only took about a second.  Try adding the new sheet and formatting before copying to it.

Comment: You might try putting `debug.print timer` at the start, before and after `Application.PrintCommunication = True`. You may be setting everything in a timely manner but stalling due to slow printer communication.

Comment: @Jeeped Never even thought of how long it would take to communicate with the printer.  I'm on a Mac using Excel for Windows via Parallels software.  Any time I print from windows it takes forever because my printer is installed on my Mac.  I did used the debug.print timer you suggested and it took 2.7 seconds.  I'm assuming this is just the time it took to find the printer, not to actually run the macro??  The user(s) for this will using Windows (not Parallels) so it should eliminate the problem.  I'll test it in their environment and see if that eliminates the problem.

Comment: Just wanted to post this as it has resolved my issue.  I have Adobe installed (via Parallels) on Windows.  When I changed to print to Adobe my times went from 2.66seconds and higher to as low as .12seconds.  BIG difference.  I would have never thought of this on my own so Thank You so much for helping me out on this.  --It's a fine line of (1) continuing to bang my head on my screen and (2) finally asking for help.  I usually wait until my head hurts.